# Why sqlite autoincrement int cant be null ?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, auto-increment

According to [Docs](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1) one can pass `null` to an `AUTOINCREMENT` column to achieve auto increment function, **BUT** , when the column is `int`, obviously one cant pass `null` to it.

How can this be solved ?

```
dbhelper.addEntry(new Entry(intCantBeNull, "StringOK"));
```

Comment: if you don't pass a value to that field, then SQLite will use an auto-incremented integer value. Or you can use the Integer class, which accept null values

Comment: that was my first guess, but no, it doesnt. @user2340612

Comment: Please post your insert code so we can better help you to leave out the autoincrement column value.

Comment: well if you use the SQLiteDatabase `insert` method and in the `ContentValues` parameter you don't specify a value for the `auto-incremented column` then you'll get an `auto-incremented value`

Comment: You _can_ (and generally _do_) pass NULL in for auto-incrementing fields, and sqlite3 does what it's supposed to do. The problem you appear to be running into is an API issue (which someone other than me will have to help with). NULL is not Java's `null` unless the API says it is.

Comment: @mah are you sure about the API ? Im running on level 11

Comment: @Shervin I'm not sure at all about the API, which is why I said someone other than me will have to help ;) I'm sure that sqlite3 works as documented in this regard and I'm sure that Java's `null` can only be related to SQL's `NULL` if the API makes that translation, but I'm not sure what the API does.

Answer (score 0):

You can try inserting your data like below,

Suppose you have two fields Id ( which is autoincrement ) and name ( TEXT )

```
Insert into yourTableName(name) values ( "StackOverflow" );
```

Here actually you are passing `NULL` into your `AUTOINCREMENT` field which is handled by SQLite automatically.

Comment: Im aware of this SQL-y way. I want something to work with my dbhelper @user3322955

Comment: @Shervin , that page already says taht `the NULL is automatically converted into an integer which is one greater than the largest value of that column over all other rows in the table, or 1 if the table is empty.`

Comment: @Shervin, sorry, I am not getting you.

Comment: what is said on that page is not what I'm experiencing. you will get error for leaving out the "Autoincrement" field.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47756/discussion-between-user3322955-and-shervin)